# What is difference between these two codes?

Tags: python

```
Turtle=Animal("Turtle")
Turtle.set_category("reptile")
```

and

```
class Turtle(Animal):
    category="reptile"
```

While learning object composition in python i came across a problem in which latter worked but former did not.

this was the class

```
class Animal:
    name = ""
    category = ""
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def set_category(self, category):
        self.category = category
```

Comment: In one case, `Turtle` is an object of type `Animal`.  In the second case, `Turtle` is a class, and you haven't created any objects at all.

Comment: And would you please quit undoing all the fixes we have made to your formatting?

Comment: In my experience, people who ask "what is the difference between..." are usually trying to compare two things that *make no sense to compare*. This is one of those times. At any rate, you really need to follow a tutorial and understand the fundamentals, and if you get stuck then ask a *specific* question that *makes reference to a specific thing you read in the tutorial*.

Answer (score 1):

These two sequences should behave the same:

```
turtle=Animal("Turtle")
turtle.set_category("reptile")
```

and

```
class Turtle(Animal):
    category="reptile"
    name = "Turtle"

turtle = Turtle()
```

The two `turtle` objects will behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code you are defining an instance of the `Animal` class stored in the `Turtle` variable, whereas in the second piece of code you are defining a new class called `Turtle` that will inherit from the `Animal` class.

Read more about class objects here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects
Read more about class inheritance here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance